# Posting a master and details on save

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am completely new to the MVC and struggling with concept that would be easy in webform application.

I am implementing a functionality where I have to allow a user to add multiple phone number for Home, Work and mobile on a single view. So the view has below fields.

Customer Name
Customer Email

List box to select: Home/Mobile/Work
Textbox for the selected category

User is allowed to add multiple contact numbers and finally on save it should be stored in Customer table as well as customer's contacts table which has Customer's ID, Contact Type and Number.

It would be great help if you have working example of it.

Thanks..

Comment: Why would you not just have 3 textboxes, one for each type, and make them optional?

Comment: There could be more than 3 textboxes, 'n' numbers for each category

Comment: Then you will need javascript/jquery to dynamically add new controls and ensure they are correctly named (with indexers) for postback